# Finding zero-length LINESTRINGs the wrong way gives funny answer

Tags: postgis, linestring

I tried

```
select st_astext(geom) from table where st_pointn(geom, 1) = st_pointn(geom, 2)
```

But I get some results which don't match the criteria. For example: `LINESTRING(-117.1642086 34.2779308,-117.1642145 34.2779305)`

Why do I get the wrong answer for that query?

(I have since changed my query to use `st_length`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is not correct to compare geometries with "=" operator but you must use "ST_Equals" instead. This is your original case:

```
SELECT ST_ASText(st_pointn(foo.geom, 1)), ST_AsText(st_pointn(foo.geom, 2)) from (
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-117.1642086 34.2779308,-117.1642145 34.2779305)') as geom
) foo
where st_pointn(foo.geom, 1) = st_pointn(foo.geom, 2);


"POINT(-117.1642086 34.2779308)";"POINT(-117.1642145 34.2779305)"
```

Odd result which seems to suggest the different points are equal. However, result from this query with ST_Equals gives an empty result:

```
SELECT ST_ASText(st_pointn(foo.geom, 1)) as point1, ST_AsText(st_pointn(foo.geom, 2)) as point2 from (
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-117.1642086 34.2779308,-117.1642145 34.2779305)') as geom
) foo
where ST_Equals(st_pointn(foo.geom, 1), st_pointn(foo.geom, 2))
```